# Knockout with Jquery UI datepicker date display

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Please see this link for details http://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/5p6Uz/4/

Can we do the range in Datepicker, If first date choose [ 10/12/2012 ] then second date shouldn't be before 10/12/2012, Customer can select date after ex.[10/13/2012] in datepicker.

Could anyone explain me how to implement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this will do http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: @naveen i wanted to use with knockout Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the previous row's data as the new min, it makes it challenging.

Working demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/5p6Uz/24/

There were two things that were required.

1. Added a computed observable to pass the previous row's choosedate value to the current row.
2. Added a new minDate binding to set the mindate option on the date picker.

This is not a completed fiddle.  It doesn't properly handle adds or deletes.  This is because the ko.computables need to be rebuilt.

---

**EDIT:**

Updated to handle add / delete methods. Interesting problem, trying to transfer information between two different rows in the table.  Good challenge.

Soution at http://jsfiddle.net/5p6Uz/34/.

Comment: I'll work on it tonight.  Should be able to get it done for you.

Comment: I really appreciate your hard work and giving me right answer

Comment: Your welcome.  Actually, I should also thank you for an interesting problem.